# How can I return an object that "does not exist in the current context" from a Using statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

So I got a Blazor edit page that needs to update fields. My main issue is trying to return the object "ResponseDto" with the changes made and refresh the screen;

Call from blazor page:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" style="float: right;"   @onclick="@SaveChanges">Save Changes</button>
</div>

protected async Task SaveChanges()
{
    clientdto = await apiService.SaveDtoAsync(ClientID, clientdto);
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

API service

```
public async Task<ClientDto> SaveDtoAsync(int ClientID, [FromBody] ClientDto ClientDto)
    {
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        var Url = "api/clients/" + Convert.ToInt32(ClientID);
        var SerializedClientDto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ClientDto);
        using (var RequestClientDto = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, Url))
        {
            RequestClientDto.Content = new StringContent(SerializedClientDto, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            RequestClientDto.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            using (var ResponseClientDto = await _httpClient.SendAsync(RequestClientDto))
            {
                if (!ResponseClientDto.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    ResponseClientDto.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
                else
                {
                    var Response = await ResponseClientDto.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var ResponseDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDto>(Response);
                }
            }
        }
        return ResponseDto;
    }
```

Comment: Put the return statement inside the using clause

Comment: I tried that and it throws a compiler error 'APiService.SaveDtoAsync(int, ClientDto)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @AlEx: What should the method return if the `else` block is never entered?

Comment: Im hoping it returns ClientDto updated with the new values to display

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with Blazor, you're simply trying to use a variable in a higher scope than it exists.

But before you can decide on a correction, first you need to decide what the method should return if you never populate `ResponseDto`.  For example, if it should throw an exception then you can move the `return` to where you define the variable (don't need the variable at all, really) and throw an exception at the end of the method:

```
//...
            else
            {
                var Response = await ResponseClientDto.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDto>(Response);
            }
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Some meaningful error message");
}
```

Or if it should return `null` or an empty instance of the type, you can do that:

```
//...
            else
            {
                var Response = await ResponseClientDto.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDto>(Response);
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // or: return new ClientDto();
}
```

It's really up to you how you want the method to behave, and there are a variety of ways to structure it.  All you need to ensure is:

1. You use variables in the scope that they exist.
2. All possible logical code paths in the method produce a result.  (Either return a value or throw an exception.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat simplified version and should be equal to the call above.

```
public async Task<ClientDto> SaveDtoAsync(int clientID, [FromBody] ClientDto clientDto)
{
    _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

    var response = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, $"api/clients/{clientID}");
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //TODO: add error handling 
        return null; //or default;
    }

    using (MemoryStream ms = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    {
       return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ClientDto>(ms);
    }
}
```

I'm using the [Http extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.putasjsonasync?view=net-5.0) that can make http calls more readable and manageble. The other trick to note here I'm not reading the response content as string, instead I use memory stream. With new Json parser we can safe some allocations this way. This means less GC pressure. (Small side note for parsing large json (over 1000 objects) there is known performance bug).

---

For a less change required version @David already posted an excelente answear.

Comment: thank you for your response, I do get a compiler error on the PutAsJsonAsync though  "HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'PutAsJsonAsync' and no accessible extension method 'PutAsJsonAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" It only lets me use "PutJsonAsync" but throws another compiler error "Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable", this is so frustrating.....

Comment: You have to install the nuget for the extension methods. `dotnet add package System.Net.Http.Json --version 3.2.1`
You can find other installation ways on nuget.org.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Json/3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

@ZoltBendes Thank you so much for the help, I managed to get it to work "partially", It runs but I get back a "StatusCode: 204, ReasonPhrase: 'No Content' so technically its not taking the changes even though everything seems to be working fine. This is how I got to work, once again "partially"

```
        HttpResponseMessage ResponseClientDto = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/clients/{ClientID}", ClientDto);
        if (!ResponseClientDto.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            ResponseClientDto.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/clients/{ClientID}");
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientDto>(responseContent);
```